# Problem debugging and running an App in Flutter (VSCode)

Tags: flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documentos\flutter-projects\hello_world\android\build.gradle' line: 15
- What went wrong:
  Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documentos\flutter-projects\hello_world\android\build.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> build file 'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documentos\flutter-projects\hello_world\android\build.gradle': 15: token recognition error at: '#' @ line 15, column 35.
> keyPassword = "qwert%$#@!"
> ^

1 error
2

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 43s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0):

have you clean your gradle with `./gradlew clean`, run this command in your android directory project and then try `./gradlew build`, if build is unsuccessful then try to looking at the log and see what's wrong with your project. based on my previous experience the problem is mostly from the outdated import, if that's the problem then try to update your package

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these two commands:

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

Please try upgrading your flutter first using `flutter upgrade`, then try cleaning your enviroment using `flutter clean` and then installing all the packages again using `flutter pub get`. This might fix your issue, you can try debugging your application again.